# How to add prefix to multi index columns at particular level?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'foo'), ('a', 'bar'),
                                       ('b', 'foo'), ('b', 'bah')])

miindex=np.arange(3)
dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(3 * len(micolumns)).reshape((len(miindex), len(micolumns))),
                     index=miindex, columns=micolumns).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

  a       b    
  bar foo bah foo
0   1   0   3   2
1   5   4   7   6
2   9   8  11  10
```

And I want to add prefix to column at level zero, how can I do that?

Currently I'm renaming the columns like below, and it feels redundant.

```
df_new = dfmi.rename(columns=dict(zip(dfmi.columns.levels[0],'pre_'+dfmi.columns.levels[0])),level=0) 

    pre_a     pre_b    
    bar foo   bah foo
0     1   0     3   2
1     5   4     7   6
2     9   8    11  10
```

There is no level parameter for `add_prefix` function. Is there any similar function for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One quick away is:

```
dfmi.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(f'pre_{a}',b) for a,b in dfmi.columns])
```

or `rename` with `mapper`:

```
dfmi.rename(mapper=lambda x: f'pre_{x}', 
            axis='columns',
            level=0,
            inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

An unusual way would be:

```
dfmi.stack(level=1).add_prefix('pre_').unstack().dropna(how='all',axis=1)
```

---

```
  pre_a      pre_b      
    bar  foo   bah   foo
0   1.0  0.0   3.0   2.0
1   5.0  4.0   7.0   6.0
2   9.0  8.0  11.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

What i will do

```
s=dfmi.columns.to_frame()
s[0]+='XXXX'
dfmi.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(s)
dfmi
0 aXXXX     bXXXX    
1   bar foo   bah foo
0     1   0     3   2
1     5   4     7   6
2     9   8    11  10
```